# Orange 3: How to transform TEST set when TRAIN set pre-processed with Preprocess Widget

Tags: orange

When using Orange3 Preprocess widget's normalize or PCA function on the TRAIN dataset, is there a way to transform TEST dataset using the parameters of the TRAIN set without using the Python Script?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late answer,

you can use apply domain widget, where :

- input data to the widget:

  - template data ( the preprocessed data on train set)
  - data ( the test set that you want it to be transformed into the space of train data)
- output data:

  - transformed test data into the space of train data

for more details you can visit orange3 docs site:

https://orangedatamining.com/blog/2021/2021-08-13-apply-domain/